# How to create bindings in c# code by using x:Bind or the same thing?

Tags: uwp

The problem is the following: I can't get from Binding to change the properties of the element after creating the object. For example, I created a button and binded Background to the value:

```
CoreButton.SetBinding(BackgroundProperty, new Binding() { Source = subtitles.settings.Background, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged , Mode= BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

```
public class Settings:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;     
        public SolidColorBrush background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
        public SolidColorBrush Background
        {
            get
            {
                return background;
            }
            set
            {
                background = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Background"));
            }
        }
```

This works, but only when the button is initialized, in the future the value does not change, even despite INotifyPropertyChanged.
Next, I tried to do the same thing in xaml using x:Bind and everything worked:

```
<Button x:Name="CoreButton" Opacity="0.75"  Background="{x:Bind Path=subtitles.settings.Background, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

But I need to create bindings in the C#code. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works, but only when the button is initialized,

The problem is your pass the the wrong source value for binding method. In your current scenario the source value should be `subtitles`. And you need specific `Path` like this `Path = new PropertyPath("settings.Background")`.

**Solution**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
     public Subtitles subtitles { get; set; }
     public MainPage()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         subtitles = new Subtitles(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
         CoreButton.SetBinding(BackgroundProperty, new Binding()
         {
             Source = subtitles,
             Path = new PropertyPath("settings.Background"),
             UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
             Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
         });
     }

     private void CoreButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         subtitles.settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
     }
 }
 public class Subtitles
 {
     public Subtitles(SolidColorBrush brush)
     {
         settings = new Settings() { Background = brush };
     }
     public Settings settings { get; set; }
 }
 public class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private SolidColorBrush background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
     private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
     public SolidColorBrush Background
     {
         get
         {
             return background;
         }
         set
         {
             background = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
 }
```